# Error using horzcat Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent. Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, concatenation

I am geting the Error using horzcat
Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent.

I am trying to do the following:

```
Y = [single(time)' Bmag' Br' Bt' Bn']
```

However, my arrays are of the same size:

[image]

Comment: Can you break the problem down? Currently you have 5 arrays being concatenated, do 4 of them work? Try using a proper transpose (`.'`) instead of a complex conjugate transponse (`'`)? A [mcve] would help us debug, currently we can't reproduce your issue as all we don't have your workspace

Comment: Looks like you fat-fingered your time array to 1x3060 rather than 1x3600!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your time array is 1x3060 instead of 1x3600.